# Use GroupSizeReductionOrder in RibbonControlsLibrary with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I am using the RibbonControlsLibrary (.Net 4.0) for my ribbons. My implementation is completely realized using MVVM.
Now I like to use the benefit of the resizing feature. But I can't set the reduction order of the group boxes. This is because I have to define the names of the group boxes in a special order. I can't set the names of the group boxes, because I am using data templates.
I tried to bind the name of the ribbon group box user controls to a property on the datacontext, but as I supposed this doesn't work.

So, do I have any chance to set the ribbon group box user control names to a property of the data context?

Comment: Could you paste the source code?

Answer (score 0):

## Setting the RibbonGroups' names

There may be others solutions, mine is to implement a [Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) that sets the RibbonGroup's name in the OnAttached method.

```
public class RibbonGroupNameBehavior : Behavior<RibbonGroup>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        GroupeCommandesViewModel groupeCommandesViewModel = this.AssociatedObject.DataContext as GroupeCommandesViewModel;
        if (groupeCommandesViewModel != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Name = groupeCommandesViewModel.Nom;
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to add a try-catch block around the assignment...

## Using the behavior

As you are using DataTemplates, I think you'll have to assign the behavior to the RibbonGroups with a Style.
I have been using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406679/428494) with success.
As you'll see, my behavior's code does not provide the required dependency property, you'll have to add it.

Here is my shortened Ribbon's style :

```
<r:Ribbon.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:Ribbon}">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ListeCommandes, Converter={StaticResource CommandesToGroupesConverter}}" />
                    <Setter Property="GroupSizeReductionOrder" Value="{Binding ListeCommandesOrdreRedimensionnement}" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyleSelector">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ribbonVM:RibbonGroupStyleSelector>
                                <ribbonVM:RibbonGroupStyleSelector.GenericStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonGroup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RibbonGroupStyle}" />
                                </ribbonVM:RibbonGroupStyleSelector.GenericStyle>
                            </ribbonVM:RibbonGroupStyleSelector>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</r:Ribbon.Style>
```

And my RibbonGroup's style :

```
<Style x:Key="RibbonGroupStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonGroup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RibbonControlStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Header"       Value="{Binding Libellé}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource"  Value="{Binding Commandes}" />

    <Setter Property="CanAddToQuickAccessToolBarDirectly" Value="False" />

    <Setter Property="ihm_behaviors:RibbonGroupNameBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

## Databinding the GroupSizeReductionOrder property

If you look at the definition of the GroupSizeReductionOrder property, you'll see it's a StringCollection with a TypeConverter StringCollectionConverter.
From what I have seen, this converter only converts from string to StringCollection.
So your property shoud be either a string or a StringCollection.